# How to change the sprite of a UI Image element at runtime to one in my Assets folder?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite

I want a UI `Image` component to change the sprite displayed when it is clicked.

For example the displayed sprite is at first a red box, and when clicked, I want to change it into a green box.

How do I do that in the `OnMouseDown()` event?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class bbox1 : MonoBehaviour {

    public static int x=1;
    Image image;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        image = GameObject.Find ("box1").GetComponent<Image> ();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        if (x == 1) {
            x=2;
            image.sprite = greenbox;
        }
    }
}
```

Presently in my script, I don't know how to get a reference to the replacement sprite (`greenbox`), so I can set it on `image.sprite`. The sprite is in my Assets folder - how do I load it?

Comment: How have you attempted to code a solution for this? What has your research turned up?

Comment: image = GameObject.Find ("box1").GetComponent<Image> ();

Comment: that is what i have tried. is that right? i dont know how to get the sprite component of my object

Comment: then after getting it trying to overridesprite the sprite of my object

Comment: Okay - if you were able to successfully get a reference to the image component, then [the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Image.html) would suggest you need to set the `Image.sprite` variable. Please edit your question to show your code so far, and explain how it fails to meet your objectives.

Comment: done editing. posted my code above

Comment: Great. So which part isn't working? Is the MouseDown being detected? Have you tried executing the sprite replacement in isolation, to see if that part works?

Comment: the OnMouseDown works but i have trouble referencing the sprite i want it to change. i want it to change to a greenbox. my sprite is in my resources folder, how do i reference it then make it change to a green box?

Comment: I see - posted an answer, let me know if it achieves your objectives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you need is the [`Resources.Load()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html) method, in order to load the new sprite you want the `Image` to display. Here's an idea of how you might use it in your code (let's say the path to your sprite asset is "Sprites/GreenBox"):

```
void OnMouseDown()
{
    if (x == 1) {
        x=2;
        image.sprite = Resources.Load("Sprites/GreenBox") as Sprite;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.